# BinaryReader() Как определить конец файла

Tags: c#, файлы

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить, что файл (поток) закончился при считывании из файла? Использую BinaryReader().
Вот мой код. Ничего не получается.

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:2.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs1);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    string s = "";
    while (br.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        s = br.ReadString(); bw.Write(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для идентификации конца потока/файла, можно использовать генерируемую автоматически ошибку EndOfStreamException;
2. Можно использовать редактируемое свойство Position базового потока  FileStream, обвернутого в класс BinaryReader

ПРИМЕР:

```
FileStream File = new FileStream("D:\\StoreInfo.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader FileInfo = new BinaryReader(StoreInfo);

while (FileInfo.BaseStream.Position != FileInfo.BaseStream.Length)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Две минуты с известным поисковиком.

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084062)

Answer (score 1):

while (br.PeekChar() > -1) должно нормально работать. И на случай исключения желательно код обернуть в блок try...catch. Подробный пример можете [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.6.php) посмотреть.